# Matrix representation for *T*

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

*Let B = {1, coshx, sinhx}* be an ordered basis for *V = span(B)*

---

(i)Show that $e^x \in V$ and find it's coordinates with respect to *B*.

---

(ii)Define a linear map $T: V \to V$ by

---

### $T(f) = f'' - f'$

Write down the matrix representation for *T* with respect to the basis *B*

---

(iii) Hence, or otherwise,find the kernel and nullity of T

---

I know how to do (i)  but I don't understand part (ii) and (iii)

Comment: For (ii), figure out $T(1)$, $T(\cosh x)$, and $T(\sinh x)$ and write down their coordinates wrt $B$ as the columns of a matrix.  For (iii), once you have your matrix from part (ii) proceed as you usually would to find the kernel/ nullity of a matrix.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what it is that’s confusing you?

Comment: With respect to the B is the part that confuses me

Comment: So T(1) = 0, T(coshx) = coshx - sinhx , T(sinhx) = sinhx - coshx where do I go from there?

Comment: Now write each answer as a linear combination of the basis's elements

Comment: So (0,0,0) (0,1,-1) and (0,-1,1) ?

Comment: Yep.  Now you construct a matrix with those vectors as columns: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Okay thanks for all your help!